# ASP.net website wont work in older versions of explorer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, internet-explorer

My website works great in Crome, Foxfire and Safari and internet explorer but the tabs on the right handside dont work in internet explorer 9 or lower. I build the website using asp.net and visual studio. Can someone help me get it to work and on internet explorer 7, 8 and 9. Follow the link below and click download source code to download the sourcecode. The source code button is located below the menu bar and directly to the left of the right sidebar

http://www.disabilityallies.com/info

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not for debugging your entire site. If you can provide a [small self contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that will help us to help you. Not part of the problem , but things that should be addressed: `id` should be unique to the page; `h1` tags are for page, or at the most major section titles. Many people say there should only be 1 per page.

Comment: Another issue, and this one is relevant, HTML5 is not supported natively in [IE8 and lower](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic). This can be overcome with javascript, and there are many easy to find examples on the net.